# VAR models with de-trend time series vs VECM

Tags: time-series, econometrics, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I am working in a VAR model for an economic research. I have been reading about this but there is something i still don't get. Based in the books I have read:

1. if I have 2 time series, both are stationary in level, I can use VAR
2. if I have 2 time series with trend but they are co integrated I can use VECM with this series.
3. if I have 2 time series with trend but they are not co integrated, then I must use VAR with differences

This is based in:

*Loría, E. (2007). Econometría con aplicaciones. Editorial Pearson Prentice Hall. México.*

*Gujarati, D. N. D. N. (1992). Econometría. McGraw-Hill,.*

You can also see that in this book: [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/2)

This was so far what i knew, before i start to use some software to fit my model. Every book i have been reading about VAR never tell nothing about the inclusion of a "trend" or when to include it, and then i found [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160302040452/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/79).

This site tells me that de-trend a series is not longer necessary, you can fit a VAR with no stationary time series inside the model, using the "trend" argument you can find in some software.

my questions are:
How to use the trend inside a VAR model?
Using a VAR with trend, when i have co integration, is better than a VECM?

Comment: a VAR with deterministic trend is different from a VAR with stochastic trend, which is again different than a VECM. But yes, all of these are nonstationary.